Solution for Qualtrics 'Loop and Merge' and managing data
UPDATED 9/17 WITH EXAMPLE DF
Anyone have a solution for handling Loop and Merge data in Qualtrics? I find this is a great tool for creating a survey that is very usable, but really challenging to deal with the exported data.
I have a survey where I'm trying to learn about class offerings. The organization will get a survey, and in block one will provide basic info, and then choose from a list of topics they might offer for classes. The survey will then ask questions in a second block using loop and merge, that ask about the class times, languages class is offered in, inperson/virtual, etc. etc. This second block will repeat for each topic.
I have example of what data looks like vs. what I would like for it to look like - my actual survey has over 20 topics to choose from with 15 questions in the Loop and Merge Section.
Ideally solution would be something with how data is dealt with in Qualtrics - I am also proficient in R if anyone has a solution that involves manipulating data in R - right now I have code that selects columns and stacks them, removing NAs, but the code is cumbersome.
How data is exported:
qualtrics_output <- data.frame(
  org_name = c("Org A", "Org B", "Org C"),
  website = c("www.orgA.com", "www.orgB.com", "www.orgC.com"),
  contact = c("orgA@gmail.com", "orgB@gmail.com", "orgC@gmail.com"),
  class_topic = c("Dance, Art, Writing", "Dance, Science", "Art"),
  "1_date_time" = c("M/W, 3 - 5", "M 4 - 5", NA),
  "1_inperson_virtual" = c("inperson", "inperson", NA),
  "2_date_time" = c("Sa, 12 - 3", NA, "F, 2 - 3"),
  "2_inperson_virtual" = c("virtual", NA, "inperson"),
  "3_date_time" = c(NA, "T, 6 - 7", NA),
  "3_inperson_virtual" = c(NA, "inperson", NA),
  "4_date_time" = c("T/R, 9 - 10", NA, NA),
  "4_inperson_virtual" = c("virtual", NA, NA)
)

#1 = Dance
#2 = Art
#3 = Science
#4 = Writing

Here is how I would like to work with the data:

wanted_output <- data.frame(
  org_name = c("Org A", "Org A", "Org A", "Org B", "Org B", "Org C"),
  website = c("www.orgA.com", "www.orgA.com", "www.orgA.com", "www.orgB.com", 
              "www.orgB.com","www.orgC.com"),
  contact = c("orgA@gmail.com", "orgA@gmail.com", "orgA@gmail.com", 
              "orgB@gmail.com", "orgB@gmail.com", "orgC@gmail.com"),
  class_topic = c("Dance", "Art", "Writing", "Dance", "Science", "Art"),
  date_time = c("M/W, 3 - 5", "Sa, 12 - 3", "T/R, 9 - 10", "M 4 - 5", "T 6 - 7", 
                "F 2 -3"),
  inperson_virtual = c("inperson","virtual", "virtual", "inperson", "inperson", 
                       "inperson")
)


It will be dramatically easier for people to help if you can edit your question to include some sample data as code, e.g. by loading in R and using dput() to make a "code recipe" for that data.
